# Decimal to Binary conversion using java Errors

Tags: java

I am kind of confused is my program correct or I am missing something!

I could get an output out of it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter you String: ");
    String bin = sc.nextLine();

    int length = bin.length();
    int j = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    if (length != 0) {
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (bin.charAt(i) == "0" || bin.charAt(i) == "1") {
                String s = bin.charAt(j) + "";
                sum = (int) (sum + (Integer.valueOf(s)) * (Math.pow(2, i)));
                j++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("illegal input.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    } else {
        System.out.println("illegal input.");

    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `if (bin.charAt(i) == '0' || bin.charAt(i) == '1') {` note the single quote `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks on this line:

```
if (bin.charAt(i) == "0" || bin.charAt(i) == "1") {
```

should become

```
if (bin.charAt(i) == 0 || bin.charAt(i) == 1) {
```

Below code works fine:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
public static void main (String args []) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter you String: ");
    String  bin = sc.nextLine();

    int length = bin.length();
    int j = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    if (length != 0) {
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (bin.charAt(i) == '0' || bin.charAt(i) == '1') {
                String s = bin.charAt(j) + "";
                sum = (int) (sum + (Integer.valueOf(s)) * (Math.pow(2, i)));
                j++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("illegal input.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    } else {
        System.out.println("illegal input.");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: i fixed that part but the program still throws me an error on  import java.util.*;

Comment: You need single quotes: 0 should be `'0'`, and the same for 1.

Comment: consecutive statement on line must be separated by ';'

Comment: and on  " public static void main (String args []) {" statement ==exception declaration

Comment: What error does it throw? It works fine for me for the inputs "0123456" and "kaan" :)

Comment: Are you executing java program from command line?
Check and set proper java JDK path as it seems its not set up correctly. Also for some IDEs you have to set JAVA_HOME environmental variable.
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: What java version do you use? I run on JavaSE-10

Comment: I did not try to develop java in Xcode yet. From screenshot I can tell that Xcode doesn't make proper statycal analisys and errors are wrong. Probably you'll be better of doing it from command line. I guess it will be enough for the homework. Try javac and java commands to run the application.

And your application is making binary to decimal conversation - your title is wrong